# JSoup - login on web page, session is outdated

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to perform a login into a webchat service (unfortunately not available in English)

http://czat.wp.pl/i,1,chat.html

There are already several threads on stack overflow, which shows how to perform this kind of operation with JSoup library.

More or less it should be done as following:

```
String url = "http://czat.wp.pl/i,1,chat.html";

Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url)
.method(Connection.Method.GET)
.execute();

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
.data("i", "1")
.data("nick", "SomeFancyNickname")
.data("simg", "someCaptcha")
.data("regulamin", "tak")
.data("auth", "nie")
.cookies(loginForm.cookies())
.post();
```

The problem is, that every time I receive the same message, that session is outdated.

Is it a cookie related issue? Did I miss something?

I do not think it is related to javascript, as I it works in browsers with disabled java script.

Comment: Try it in your browser with disabled JavaScript and you will get the same result, so jsoup alone is probably not the right tool. Have a look at HtmlUnit or other headless browsers with JavaScript support.

Comment: I've tried with Firefox - javascript.enable = false & noscript turned on. Everything seems to work (except validation).

How can I repeat your test? If it is really a problem related to JavaScript, then is there any portable (to Android) way, to handle this?

Comment: Define: Everything seems to work. Also: have you removed stored cookies, before trying with disabled JS?

Comment: Now I try once again, with removed all cookies. Definition of "everything seems to work":

- There is no message, that session is outdated
- I received a new HTML content (with a lot of javascript stuff, but this can be parsed later)

Comment: Now that was quite the headscratcher, because I looked for changes in XHR and document request, but an image request changing the cookies caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Though all needed cookies seem to be set, the request redirects back to the form. Looking closely at the requests, you will notice that the cookie-values change and that it is caused by the request for the captcha image.

**Fix**

So we need an additional request for the captcha image (see `Jsoup.connect(imageUrl)...` in example code) to grab the new cookie-values and while we are at it, we can store the image for reading/processing.

**Example Code**

```
String url = "http://czat.wp.pl/i,1,chat.html";
Map<String, String> cookies;
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36";

try {
    Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).header("Host", "czat.wp.pl").execute();
    URL redirectUrl = response.url();

    cookies = response.cookies();

    String imageUrl = response.parse().select("#secImg > img").attr("abs:src").toString();

    // get captcha image and new cookies 
    System.out.println("Insert captcha code: ");

    response = Jsoup.connect(imageUrl).userAgent(userAgent).cookies(cookies).ignoreContentType(true)
            .header("Referer", redirectUrl.toString()).header("Host", "si.wp.pl")
            .header("Origin", "http://czat.wp.pl").execute();

    byte[] bytes = response.bodyAsBytes();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String captcha = scanner.nextLine();

    scanner.close();
    frame.setVisible(false);
    frame.dispose();

    cookies.putAll(response.cookies());

    // login
    String nick = "HalloWorld"; // change

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).cookies(cookies).data("i", "1").data("auth", "nie")
            .data("nick", nick).data("regulamin", "tak").data("simg", captcha)
            .header("Origin", "http://czat.wp.pl").header("Referer", "http://czat.wp.pl/i,1,chat.html")
            .post();

    if(doc.getElementById("alert") != null){
        System.err.println(doc.getElementById("alert").text());
    }else{
        // do something useful
        System.out.println(doc.text());
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Truncated Output**

```
Ogólna - Czat - Platforma nowych znajomości - WP.PL Poczta | TopNews | WP [...]
```

So evidently the alert message is gone and we have a valid session.